# Ruby on Rails session login only works when fetch link to backend is written as a React proxy, but not when it's written as a full link

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, ruby, fetch, session-cookies

I've been working on deploying a full stack web application with a React frontend/Ruby on Rails backend, but the login function only seems to work in production with a proxy link as opposed to when I write out the full link.

Here are my backend routes:

```html
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :users, only: [:create, :show, :index]

   #THIS LOGIN FUNCTION BELOW IS THE PROBLEM
  post '/login',    to: 'sessions#create'
  get '/logged_in', to: 'sessions#is_logged_in?'
  delete '/logout',   to: 'sessions#destroy'

end
```

Here are my helper functions stored in the Applications Controller

```html
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
    helper_method :login!, :logged_in?, :current_user, :authorized_user?, :logout!, :set_user
        
    def login!
          session[:user_id] = @user.id
    end
    def logged_in?
          !!session[:user_id]
    end
    def current_user
          @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
    end
    def authorized_user?
           @user == current_user
    end
    def logout!
        session.clear
    end
    def set_user
        @user = User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
    end
end
```

Here is my sessions controller, which handles the login/logout/am-i-logged in functionality with the helper methods above:

```html
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
    def create
        @user = User.find_by(username: session_params[:username])
      
        if @user && @user.authenticate(session_params[:password])
          login!
          render json: {
            logged_in: true,
            user: @user
          }
        else
          render json: { 
            status: 401,
            errors: ['Incorrect username or password, please try again.']
          }
        end
    end
    def is_logged_in?
        if logged_in? && current_user
          render json: {
            logged_in: true,
            user: current_user
          }
        else
          render json: {
            logged_in: false,
            message: 'no such user'
          }
        end
    end
    def destroy
          logout!
          render json: {
            status: 200,
            logged_out: true
          }
    end
    private
    def session_params
          params.require(:user).permit(:username, :password)
    end
end
```

Here is my frontend (when using proxy links for the backend):

```html
import React from 'react';
const Test = () => {
    function handleLoggedInClick(){
        fetch(`/logged_in`).then((r) => {
            r.json().then(results=>{
             console.log(results);
             })
            })
    }
    function handleSignupClick(){

        fetch(`/signup`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({user: {
                "username": "newroy6",
                "password": "newpass",
                password_confirmation: "newpass",
      
            }}),
          })
            .then((r) => {
            if (r.ok) {
              console.log(r.json(), "successfully created account and logged in apparently")
            } else {
              console.log("error creating account");
            }
          })
    }
    function handleLoginClick(){
        fetch(`/login`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({user: {
                "username": "newroy6",
                "password": "newpass"
      
            }}),
          })
            .then((r) => {
            if (r.ok) {
              console.log(r.json(), "successfully logged in apparently")
            } else {
              console.log("error signing in");
            }
          })
    }
    function handleSignoutClick(){
        fetch(`/logout`, { method: "DELETE"}).then((r) => {
            if (r.ok) {
               console.log(r.json())
            }
          })
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={()=>handleLoggedInClick()}>am i logged in</button>
            <button onClick={()=>handleLoginClick()}>login</button>
            <button onClick={()=>handleSignupClick()}>signup</button>
            <button onClick={()=>handleSignoutClick()}>signout</button>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Test;
```

Here is what that looks like in production:
[image: As you can see, it starts with me being logged in, then when I sign out, it says I'm not logged in, and when I sign back in, it says I'm logged in accurately. There are no other errors]

Here is what the cookies look like in the storage section of my developer tools. The local and session storages are both empty.
[image]

BUT, when I change my frontend to work without a proxy link in the package.json, and add the full link to my fetch requests, it doesn't work:

```html
import React from 'react';
const Test = () => {
    function handleLoggedInClick(){
        //THIS BELOW LINK IS WHAT WAS CHANGED
        fetch(`http:/localhost:3000/logged_in`).then((r) => {
            r.json().then(results=>{
             console.log(results);
             })
            })
    }
    function handleSignupClick(){

        fetch(`http:/localhost:3000/signup`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({user: {
                "username": "newroy6",
                "password": "newpass",
                password_confirmation: "newpass",
      
            }}),
          })
            .then((r) => {
            if (r.ok) {
              console.log(r.json(), "successfully created account and logged in apparently")
            } else {
              console.log("error creating account");
            }
          })
    }
    function handleLoginClick(){
        fetch(`http:/localhost:3000/login`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({user: {
                "username": "newroy6",
                "password": "newpass"
      
            }}),
          })
            .then((r) => {
            if (r.ok) {
              console.log(r.json(), "successfully logged in apparently")
            } else {
              console.log("error signing in");
            }
          })
    }
    function handleSignoutClick(){
        fetch(`http:/localhost:3000/logout`, { method: "DELETE"}).then((r) => {
            if (r.ok) {
               console.log(r.json())
            }
          })
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={()=>handleLoggedInClick()}>am i logged in</button>
            <button onClick={()=>handleLoginClick()}>login</button>
            <button onClick={()=>handleSignupClick()}>signup</button>
            <button onClick={()=>handleSignoutClick()}>signout</button>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Test;
```

Here is what the console log looks like when using a non proxy link for the fetch requests.

[image: Whether I login or logout, it still returns that I'm not logged in.]

The cookies are the same. My local and session storage are empty, whether or not I login.
[image]

Please help! Really not sure what the problem is.